# Upload a file to S3 Amazon from Windows application?

Tags: vb.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am new to Amazon S3 and after searching through Amazon & many sites I have made some progress.

I am creating a windows From application to upload the files. I tried with following code and it does not upload the file and I don't get any errors.

If I comment the .withKey property than file is uploaded the root of the bucket, but instead I would like to upload to a specific folder within a folder.

```
Try
        Dim fileTransferUtility As New TransferUtility(client)
        Dim request As TransferUtilityUploadRequest = New TransferUtilityUploadRequest
        Dim S3_KEY As String = "MitsTest/CVs"  'I want to upload file to CVs folder


        With request
            .BucketName = "mybucketname"
            .WithKey(S3_KEY)
            .WithFilePath("C:\Users\mitesh\Desktop\s3.txt")
            .WithTimeout(FIVE_MINUTES)
        End With
        fileTransferUtility.Upload(request)

    Catch ex As Exception

    Finally

    End Try
```

I have also tried using following and same result, I dont get any error but file does not get uploaded.

```
Dim Filepath = "C:\Users\mitesh\Desktop\s3.txt"
Dim FolderName = "MitsTest/CVs/"
Dim PutRequest As New PutObjectRequest()

    Try
        With PutRequest
            .WithBucketName("mybucketname")
            '.WithKey(FolderName + "/" + FilePath)
            .WithKey(FolderName)
            .WithFilePath(FilePath)
            .StorageClass = S3StorageClass.Standard
            .ServerSideEncryptionMethod = ServerSideEncryptionMethod.None
            '.WithContentBody(String.Empty)
            Dim response As S3Response = client.PutObject(PutRequest)
            response.Dispose()

        End With

    Catch ex As Exception
        Stop
    End Try
```

if I uncomment this line '.WithKey(FolderName + "/" + FilePath) and remove the forward slash(/) from folder name,  then I get "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method." error.

What am i missing here or doing wrong? Any help would be really appreciated.

regards

Mitesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you get the signing error is that the back slash characters in "C:\users.." are invalid for key names.  You should either replace them with forward slash or use a different value for the key name.

In your first example, you are actually trying to upload to the "MitsTest/CVs" key.  You would need to append the name of the file like this:

```
.WithKey(S3_KEY+ "/" + "s3.txt")
```

Comment: I have sorted it out myself. Here is the solution for anyone else. The solution is adding file name to the foldername.


UploadFileToS3("C:\Users\mitesh\Desktop\s3.txt", "MitsTest/CVs/s3.txt")

Dim Filepath = "C:\Users\mitesh\Desktop\s3.txt"
Dim FolderName = "MitsTest/CVs/s3.txt"